# Multi color Marker for same LineSeries - OxyPlot

Tags: c#, oxyplot

Is it possible to have a different marker style for ranges among (XY-Axis) values ? For example. The marker style is shown in steel blue color here, Can I have markers above 15 and below 13 to show another color ?

Display:

[image]

Comment: With a `TwoColorLineSeries` should be possible to have 2 zones. If what you need are 3 zones ( x<13; 13<x<15; 15<x ) maybe you should check `ScatterSeries`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oxyplot has both a `TwoColorLineSeries` and a `ThreeColorLineSeries`

Here is an example with the `ThreeColorLineSeries`

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Model = new PlotModel
        {
            Title = "Colouring example"
        };

        var series = new ThreeColorLineSeries();

        // Random data
        var rand = new Random();
        var x = 0;
        while (x < 50)
        {
            series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(x, rand.Next(0, 20)));
            x+=1;
        }

        // Colour limits
        series.LimitHi = 14;
        series.LimitLo = 7;

        // Colours
        series.Color = OxyColor.FromRgb(255,0,0);
        series.ColorHi = OxyColor.FromRgb(0,255,0);
        series.ColorLo = OxyColor.FromRgb(0,0,255);

        Model.Series.Add(series);
    }


    public PlotModel Model { get; set; }
}
```

[image: ThreeColorLineSeries example with random data]